# Redux Saga Redirect to Wordpress Page

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, redux-saga

I have a React App as a submodule in a Wordpress repo. The React App is responsible for inventory and all its pages while Wordpress is responsible for all other pages.

I have a saga function that fetches inventory details. If there's no response, I want to redirect it to another page. `yield put(push('/sales')`. The problem is that this page exists on Wordpress, not my React app. So when this is executed, it tries to find a route in react, doesn't find it, and goes to a 404 page. When I refresh, however, it loads the Wordpress page. I tried adding an absolute URL inside `yield put(push(URL))`, but it sent me on an infinite redirect loop. I was wondering if it was possible to just redirect to a Wordpress Page in redux saga.

```
function* requestInventoryDetails(action) {
  try {
    if (response && response.stockNumber) {
      .
      .
      .
    } else {
      yield put(push('/sales'))
      // window.location.reload()
    }
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(SET_ERROR('There was an error retrieving the inventory details'))
    throw err
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're navigating outside of the react app perhaps do `window.location.assign(absoluteUrl);`? Your normal redux router doesn't need to be involved. If you want to keep things testable you could put that in a separate function so it could be mocked in your saga tests.

```
function navigateToExternalPage(url) {
    window.location.assign(url);
}

function* requestInventoryDetails(action) {
  try {
    if (response && response.stockNumber) {
      .
      .
      .
    } else {
      yield call(navigateToExternalPage, externalUrl);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(SET_ERROR('There was an error retrieving the inventory details'))
    throw err
  }
}
```